# how I can edit learnpress bydefault archive-course.php page with my own style?

Tags: php, wordpress, learnpress

I want  to change some style and some facility. But here the archive-course.php don't specify all thing and I cant understand their code. Enough resourse are not available. Please help me!

Comment: Show us some code. What are you trying to do ("some" things is not enough) and which part of their code you don't understand? We need more details to answer you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @zajonc


 `if ( lp_is_archive_course_load_via_api() ) {
  echo '<div class="lp-archive-course-skeleton" style="width:100%">';
  echo lp_skeleton_animation_html( 10, 'random', 'height:20px', 'width:100%' 
                );
  echo '</div>';
 }`

here this code show a course box. its on a loop. I want to know where is the course box style and its mark up location and how i can change its style? and its location is plugin/learnpress/templates/archive-course.php